# How to optimal phpExcel when it's very slow?

Tags: php, symfony, phpexcel

I am doing exporting excel file using phpExcel. I output **2000 rows** and its execution time is about **10 seconds** . The problem is that when I output **20,000 rows** it gets error: **ERROR TIME OUT** . At first: **max_execution_time = 30**, I set it back to **max_execution_time = 60** (This value is equal to the value on the main server). Now is there a way to minimize file export time, since the data is sometimes very large..Up to a few hundred thousand rows. Please help me. Thanks. Sorry my english is not good.

- Here is my code :

---

```
         // array example
        // 20.000 rows
        $data = [
            [
                'name' => 'hello',
                'address' => 'usa',
                'birthday' => '2021-04-30'
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'hello',
                'address' => 'usa',
                'birthday' => '2021-04-30'
            ],
        ];
        // Sample processing code
        $exRow = 2;
        foreach ($data as $val) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) { // set title
                $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($i, $exRow, $val);
            }
        }
        header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="data.xls"');
        PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'Excel2007')->save('php://output');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to increase `max_execution_time` in php.ini file. if you don't access to do this just can make a `php.ini` or `user.ini` and put this text on there

`max_execution_time=500`

also you can use `yield` key to add excel row. this is help you render excel rows by lazy rendering

visit this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/keyword_yield.asp)